# Ceiling fan pull chain switch replacement

Tags: wiring, switch, ceiling-fan

[image: detail of old ceiling fan pull chain switch]Pull chain on a older ceiling fan broke inside the pull switch itself. Looked it up online, and didn't seem super complicated as a DIY.

The old switch had three wires: red, blue and black. The black one was connected to a black wire coming out of the ceiling, and the blue and red wires went straight into the switch itself. Based on the tutorial video, I separated the two black wires and cut the red and the blue wires as close to the old switch as I could. Found a three-wire switch (with red, blue and black wires) at Lowe's and replaced the old one by matching up the wires by color. The fan now works, but seems to cycle through off, medium, high, then low (in that order), which is not the order every other fan in the world does (and this fan did the normal cycle of speeds before the switch broke).

Based off some digging I did, seems like the new switch and the existing wire colors don't match up exactly and that blue needs to be paired with red, and red paired with blue. Does that make sense? Safe to try? (Obviously, the power will be off when I switch them.)

Lastly, the switch I bought is a "3-way fan light switch," so I'm not sure if maybe I instead need something that is actually made just for the fan speeds since the light is working fine.

Hope that all makes sense. Thanks for any help you can lend.

Here's the replacement switch I bought

https://www.lowes.com/pd/Harbor-Breeze-Red-Black-Scroll-Kit/50354770

ETA:
OK, I should have totally gone with my gut feeling of NOT leaving it the way it was and using it while it wasn't working properly. I was doing so while going back and forth on whether to try swapping the reds and the blues or if I should instead go looking for an exact replica of the switch I was replacing. Anyhow, thank God I was in the room where the fan was running just now. (It ran just fine for a while yesterday.) I smelled a burning smell just now, and when touching the actual fan base, it was pretty much scalding hot to the touch.

I shut the power off to that section of the house and disconnected all the wires to the switch. I think I'll suck it up and buy a new ceiling fan (this one is pretty old) and install it with the help of a buddy who knows what the hell he is doing, unlike me.

Thanks for all your input!

Comment: try more combos, it won't hurt anything if you're not connecting any of the new switch wires to any other wire that the old switch didn't use.

Answer (score 0):

In short the wires on 2way and 3way switches do not necessarily match your fans color codes.

You need to look up your fan and see which colors are actually l, m, h.

btw. you should use a 4 wire 3 speed fan pull switch, not a 3 wire light switch.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to make sure it was safe to do do before swapping those wires.
After some more digging, the instructions on the new switch tell me to align the wires (regardless of color) with certain terminals on that switch ("1," "2," and "L") based on what terminals those wires went to on the old switch. Following that, it will have me swapping things so that red is no longer with red and blue is no longer with blue, but instead one red with one blue and another pair the same way,  

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "btw. you should use a 4 wire 3 speed fan pull switch, not a 3 wire light switch."

This makes sense, but here's a dumb question: I bought a three-wire switch since that's what was in there. Where would I put the fourth wire?

I thought this was going to be pretty straightforward. Ugh.

Comment: @C.L. cheers. if the answer is what helped, please consider voting it the correct answer as to say it's been resolved.